# Deserialize JSON into DTO object and trim string values

Tags: java, json, dto

Is there a way I could deserialize JSON string into DTO object and trim all the string values in the proces with some kind of a contstructor? Or could I update my custom JSON parser code?

This is an excaple of DTO class:

```
public class House {
    @SerializedName("HouseID")
    @Expose
    private final int houseId;
    @SerializedName("Address")
    @Expose
    private final String address;
    @SerializedName("Number")
    @Expose
    private final int number;
}
```

After I receive a JSON response I parse the JSON like this:

```
Common.parseJson(arr.getJSONObject(i).toString(), House.class)
```

This is my JSON parser:

```
public static <T> T parseJson(String json, Class<T> type) {
    if (json.equals("{}")) return null;
    else {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        return gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, don't recreate the instance of `Gson` every time, reuse an existing one - you can use static field in your case.